# The mean_iou of tensorflow doesn't work correctly

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

lab = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None], dtype=tf.int32)
pred= tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None], dtype=tf.int32)

iou, conf_mat = tf.metrics.mean_iou(lab, pred, num_classes=2)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

with tf.control_dependencies([conf_mat]):
    iou = tf.identity(iou)

_iou=sess.run(iou, {lab:[[1,1,1], [1,1,1]], pred:[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]})
print(_iou)
print(sess.run('mean_iou/total_confusion_matrix:0'))
```

Above is my code to run mean_iou. The result for that code is:

```
0.0
[[0. 0.]
[0. 6.]]
```

Eventhough the confusion matrix gives the right result, my expected score for iou is 1.0. 
When I re-run the code below tf.control_dependencies, I the confusion matrix is updated to [[0,0],[0,12]] and the iou score is 1.0.

But when I try to run the update ops for confusion matrix first, and then run the iou score separately, I get the expected result.

Does that mean that tensorflow gets some bugs at this?

Comment: Its a issue being filed here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19368

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for :D

Comment: The tf metrics are not meant to be used and updated in the same call to session.run, so run the two ops separately.

Comment: Hmm, but is it better if tensorflow supports it, right? In some cases, getting the metrics score in one call is must handier to integrate the metrics to other framework, such as keras.